# Center a li item using javascript or jQuery on an horizontal scroll navbar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4.6 for a webpage, since the built-in navbar doesn't fit my needs on mobile navigation, I'm trying to modify it to work like MODE_SCROLLABLE in Android therefore, I need it to activate the link when the parent li is centered on the scroll and the active element display at the center.

To clarify the things up I have added a working sample (since it's intended to be used in mobile reduced width devices it needs to be inspected in chrome as mobile), you can scroll it horizontally but to activate the link you have to press it, and it doesn't center on the element when the element is active (or pressed).

(If you want to tryit out just use the keyboard arrow keys left and right)

```js
var lastScrollLeft = 0;
var anchoLi = $('#navegacion').width();
var anchoTotal = anchoLi * 4;
console.log(anchoLi);
console.log(anchoTotal);
$('#navegacion').scroll(function () {
  var documentScrollLeft = $('#navegacion').scrollLeft();
  if (lastScrollLeft != documentScrollLeft) {
    console.log('scroll x');
    lastScrollLeft = documentScrollLeft;
    console.log(lastScrollLeft);
     if (lastScrollLeft > anchoLi - 50 && lastScrollLeft < anchoLi * 2   ){
      $('#navegacion li').removeClass('active');
      $('#what').addClass('active');
    } else if(lastScrollLeft > anchoLi * 2 - 50 && lastScrollLeft < anchoLi * 3 ){
      $('#navegacion li').removeClass('active');
      $('#where').addClass('active');
    } else if (lastScrollLeft > anchoLi * 3  -25 && lastScrollLeft < anchoLi * 4){
        $('#navegacion li').removeClass('active');
        $('#when').addClass('active');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
    section#segunda-nav{
        background: blue;
    }
    #segunda-nav li {
    min-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    }
    #navegacion.nav-tabs {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /*// IE 10+*/
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;/*// Firefox*/}
  #navegacion.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
  #navegacion.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus,
  #navegacion.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
  border-width: 0;
}
#navegacion.nav-tabs>li>a {
  border: none;
  color: #FFF;
}
#navegacion.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
#navegacion.nav-tabs>li>a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid cyan;     
  background: transparent;
}
#navegacion.nav-tabs>li>a::after {
  content: "";  
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 1px;
  transition: all 250ms ease 0s;
  transform: scale(0);
}
#navegacion.nav-tabs>li.active>a::after,
#navegacion.nav-tabs>li:hover>a::after {
  transform: scale(1);
}
#navegacion.tab-nav>li>a::after {
  background: #21527d none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  color: #fff;
}
#navegacion.tab-pane {
  padding: 15px 0;
}
#navegacion.tab-content {
  padding: 20px
}

#navegacion.nav-tabs::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none; /*Safari and Chrome*/
}
.card {
  background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: block;
}

#navegacion.nav>li>a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
#navegacion.nav{
    flex-wrap: inherit; 
}
li.active a{
  color: red!important;
  font-weight: bold;
}
li.active{
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="segunda-nav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <ul id="navegacion" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li id="description" role="presentation" class="active"><a data-target="" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">DESCRIPTION</a></li>
                    <li id="what" role="presentation"><a data-target="#informacion-programa" data-slide-to="1" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="active">WHAT?</a></li>
                    <li id="where" role="presentation"><a data-target="#informacion-programa" data-slide-to="2" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">WHERE?</a></li>
                    <li id="when" role="presentation"><a data-target="#informacion-programa" data-slide-to="3" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">WHEN?</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap classes work in such a way that they cannot be overwritten.

Bootstrap doesn't provide much flexibility to components, perhaps you can build the navbar from scratch and add your own functionality or you can opt to other CSS frameworks like Tailwind and MaterialUI(if you're using ReactJS)

Comment: I know that built-in functions does not work like this, therefore I'm overriding the functionality, as you can see (if you inspect in as a mobile device with chrome you can freely scroll) but it doesn't center on a li and it doesn't trigger the "action" on the li a item. This could be done with javascript.